# Degree vs Valence of a vertex in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, simplicial-complex

To my understanding, "degree" and "valence" mean the same thing: the number of edges incident to a vertex (including multiplicity for loops).

Is there a difference in the contexts in which they are used?

Answer (score 3):

Both terms are equivalent. However, the term "degree" is used more often these days. In old publications, such as the ones of Erdős (c.f. "On a valence problem in extremal graph theory", Erdős and Simonovits, 1972), the term valence is ocurring more frequently.

In today's graph theoretical literature, however, it has almost disappeared (standard works such as Bondy's and Murty's "Graph Theory", already no longer mention it, and it is not appearing in their older work called "Graph Theory with applications" (1972), either). Diestel's "Graph Theory" uses both terms equivalently ("The degree (or valency) [...] of a vertex $v$ is the number of edges at $v$", p.14). However, he mostly uses the term "degree".

In chemical graph theory, one often tries to strictly separate the terms in order to make a clear distinction between the valence of chemical bonds and an abstract graph theoretic model (see for example "A review on molecular topology: applying graph theory to drug discovery and design" by Amigó et. al.).

Whether there are other applications in which the term "valence" takes on a specifically different meaning than the term "degree", I can't say for sure. In pure graph theory it does not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I wanted to confirm that there are no other meanings in topology/geometry/algebraic combinatorics as well!

Comment: There is no different meaning in algebraic combinatorics. The term appears there only in connection with the attempt to solve problems in graph theory by means of algebraic methods. There might be different meanings in topology, however I don't think that the terms valency or degree are assigned a different meaning anywhere when talking about graphs in the same breath. This would cause confusion since these terms are well established.

Answer (score 0):

Valence also has a meaning in complex dynamics -- the number of K-rays that land on each point of a periodic orbit (found in Milnor's Periodic Orbits, External Rays, and the Mandelbrot Set: An Expository Account).